# Maven - import transitively provided dependencies into project

Tags: maven

I have a project A which has some dependencies. Some of them have a `provided` scope.

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some-artifact</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

Now I have another project B which imports A:

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>my-group</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-project-a</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

All dependencies in project A are imported transitively in project B.

However, the `provided` dependencies in project A, such as `some-group:some-artifact`, are not. Is it also possible to import the `provided` dependencies from A into B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'provided' scope is not transitive and therefore not inherited.

Dependent on your context you either have to add the dependency manually or you may depend on a common parent POM or a BOM (Bill of Materials).

Here is more information on the scopes and BOMs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html